# Find the maximum and minimum in the Polynomial equation

Tags: polynomials

Let $P(x)=a_0+a_1x^2+a_2x^4+....+a_nx^{2n}$ be a polynomial in a real variable $x$ with $0<a_0<a_1<a_2......<a_n$. The function $P(x)$ has

(A) neither a maximum nor a minimum

(B) only one maximum

(C) only one minimum

(D) only one maximum and only one minimum

My approach is as follow $P'(x)=2a_1x+4a_2x^3+....+2na_nx^{2n-1}$

$P'(x)=x(2a_1+4a_2x^2+....+2na_nx^{2n-2})$

AT $x=0$ the sign of $P'(x)$ changes from negative to positive hence only one minimum which is the correct choice but what is the role of $0<a_0<a_1<a_2......<a_n$.

Comment: Hint: $P$ is an even function and it is strictly increasing on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Extending the hint of @geetha290krm, in order to conclude that $~P~$ has no maximum, you also need to conclude that for $~x > 0,~$ you have that as $~x~$ increases, $~P'(x)~$ never decreases.  In fact, although it is not necessary, you actually know that as positive $~x~$ increases, $~P'(x)~$ increases.  That is, the fact that for positive $~x, ~P(x)~$ is strictly increasing is (itself) insufficient.  A function can be strictly increasing and still be bounded.

Comment: That is a very complicated argument. There is no need to look at $P'(x)$ at all. @user2661923

Comment: @geetha290krm It depends on your point of view.  I think that the original hint/comment that you gave is a good one.  However, at the same time, it is important for the OP (i.e. original poster) to have their intuition stretched so that they realize that a function can be strictly increasing and still be bounded.  Your first hint/comment, which I like, did need to be extended so that the OP's intuition was stretched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $P(-x) = P(x)$, it suffices to consider only $x  \ge 0$. And $0 < a_0 < a_1 < a_2 < ... < a_n$, we have: $P(x) \ge a_0$, and $P(0) = a_0$. Thus there is only **one absolute minimum** value at $x = 0$ when $P_{\text{min}} = P(0) = a_0$. I forgot to mention that the role of $0 < a_1 < a_2 < ...< a_n$ is to ensure that the tail polynomial:  $a_1x^2 + a_2x^4+...+a_nx^{2n}$ is always $ \ge 0$ regardless of the $x's$ ( whether it is positive, $0$, or negative ), and also that the monotonicity increasing of the sequence of the coefficients $a_j$'s is **not** **required** in order to achieve the minimum of $f(x)$.